# What is meaning of 'exit 0' in shell script?

Tags: shell

I recently deployed a script

```
exit_job(){
echo "$1"
exit 0
}
```

I searched the web and found that the correct exit code. Can someone explain `exit 0`?

Comment: can some one explain exit 0?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html might be helpful!

Comment: Check [Wikipedia's article on "Exit status"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

Answer (score 6):

`0` is the shell script `success` code. Thus if you echo something other than this it will be returning error code, and if not handled would break your script.